# Change link color based in background color?

Tags: user-interface, colors, hyperlink, user-experience, contrast

Our white-background webpages use the blue hyperlinks as shown in the image below.

Occasionally we have dash-bordered yellow information sections on a white webpage as shown. In that case someone said the blue hyperlink text was harder to see on their iPad, because there was not enough contrast between that blue and yellow.

If white correlates with the blue shown, is there a color formula to calculate what a darker blue should be for that yellow background?

[image]

Comment: There is a css property which you could apply for anchor tag 'mix-blend-mode: darken;' Please see if that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

1. Getting the % R G B difference from white to the blue
2. Applying the % to the yellow.

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

By the way, this is with CSS mix-blend-mode: darken;

[image]

And there is another answer at:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/144624/change-link-color-based-in-background-color/144627#144627